# Autenticação Login Android

Tags: android, http, login, autenticação, autenticação-http

O app que desenvolvi para um cliente é composto por uma tela de login nativa e eu preciso fazer a autenticação do login enviando para URL da loja do cliente que está em ASP os dados de acesso (usuário e senha), recuperando se é válido, para então abrir para ele uma WebView contendo essa loja ASP com o usuário já logado.

Preciso fazer esse login intermediário no Android fora da WebView pois ele quer que eu implemente uma função que mantém o usuário logado depois do primeiro login, o que não é possível fazer na WebView (eu acho).

Me ajudem por favor, enviando links, me dando uma luz, não tenho noção nem de como procurar, muito menos como proceder.

Agradeço muito desde já!

Comment: Como vai ser essa autenticação? Você vai mandar credenciais pro service e ele vai te retornar um ticket (semelhante ao CAS)? Ou uma vez autenticado com as credenciais o usuário estará sempre logado?

Comment: Não sei se seu cliente disponibiliza de um webapi de autenticação, pois poderia consumir um webapi para autenticar e depois de autenticado enviar para o webview.

Comment: Acho que eu deixei um pouco confusa minha explicação, vou reformular pois talvez tenha um jeito mais fácil de fazer do que o que estou pensando e tentando fazer.

Eu já tenho um app com uma WebView que carrega a URL do cliente. Como está hoje ele loga dentro da WebView. 

Não sei se tem como, mas seria mais fácil se eu tivesse como receber o usuário e senha que ele insere dentro dos campos de login do formulário dentro do WebView para dentro do Android mantê-lo logado invés de fazer essa tela de login intermediária que manda o login e senha para a URL e etc. Sabem de algo a respeito disso?